# List insert at index that is well out of range - behaves like append

Tags: python, python-2.7

I had a list

```
 a = [1, 2, 3]
```

when I did

```
a.insert(100, 100)

[1, 2, 3, 100]
```

as list was originally of size 4 and I was trying to insert value at index 100 , it behaved like append instead of throwing any errors as I was trying to insert in an index that did not even existed .

Should it not throw

> IndexError: list assignment index out of range

exception as it throws when 
I attempt doing

```
a[100] = 100
```

**Question :**
1. Any idea Why has it been designed to silently handle this instead of informing the user with an exception ?

**Personal Opinion :**

Lets see how other languages behave in such a situation :

**Ruby :**

```
    > a = [1, 2]
    > a[100] = 100
    > a
 => [1, 2, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, 100]
```

The way ruby handles this is pretty clear and sounds meaningful at least to me .

**Java :**

In java the method .add(index, value) if applied with index that is out of range(on arraylist , linkedlist for example) will throw 
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException .

So what I felt was either it should throw exception(as java does) or insert null in the range in between (as ruby handles it ).
But the silent way of handling in python is just flummoxing .

**UPDATE (16 Sep 2014 IST 8:30 AM) :**

As suggested by one of the answerers I posted this question in python-dev and I got a response . It can be seen in this [python dev mailing list thread](http://code.activestate.com/lists/python-dev/132588/) . If you find that the thread link has changed, you can find the answer by doing a [google search](https://www.google.com/search?btnG=1&pws=0&q=%5BPython-Dev%5D+List+insert+at+index+that+is+well+out+of+range+-+behaves+like+append&gws_rd=ssl) for the title of question appended at the beginning with python dev.

Comment: `a.insert(len(a), x)` is supposed to act just like `a.append(x)` for connivence. My guess is that it handles any int above `len(a)` in the same way. The official python docs probably only recommends `len(a)` as a convenient way to make sure your always inputing a number greater than the length of the list. Source: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html

Comment: [There's actually an if statement](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/d3939f602e1f/Objects/listobject.c#l262) in the `insert` implementation that specifically handles converting any insertion point larger than `len(list)` to `len(list)`.

Comment: Your best bet to get the reason *why* Python chose this implementation rather than an implementation like Ruby's, or throwing an exception, is to ask on the python-list or python-dev mailing lists.

Comment: @dano you should post an answer. You solved it.

Comment: @agconti IMO that's not really the answer to the question. The OP wants to know *why* Python does this, not how it's implemented. And I don't know why it behaves this way, as opposed to say, throwing an exception if the insertion point is larger than `len(list)`.

Comment: @dano, I see you point, but it seems the it just may be for connivence like the docs say with `list.insert(len(list), x)`. We wont know for sure until documentation states it, but it seems like the odds are pretty good.

Comment: @agconti Yes, that's a reasonable guess. But still just a guess! And as I mentioned in an earlier comment, the definitive answer would come from a core dev on the Python mailing list.

Comment: As per your suggestion I have raised it in python dev list python-dev@python.org . But I don't know where to see the thread. any help ?

Comment: @HarishKayarohanam When someone responds, you'll get an email. You can also see an archive of all posts this month [here](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2014-September/thread.html). Your email is at the end of the list.

Comment: Ya Thank you . will wait for response .

Comment: In future, please point these kinds of questions to just python-list, not python-dev. This sort of thing doesn't belong on the dev list. Thanks! :)

The Python insert method is quite different from Ruby's automatic list extension on assignment. With the latter, you would definitely expect it to put it at that position, which is what you see. When you insert(), you would expect the length of the list to increase by exactly one, which is what you see.

Comment: Ya sure I was new to this so committed this mistake. Will follow your suggestion .

Comment: This is arguably a duplicate of [Why substring slicing index out of range works in Python?](//stackoverflow.com/q/9490058), because `list.insert()` is documented to be the same as a slice assignment.

Answer (score 17):

From the *[docs](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html)*:

> **list.insert(i, x)** 
>   Insert an item at a given position. The first argument is the index of the element before which to insert, so
>   a.insert(0, x) inserts at the front of the list, and a.insert(len(a),
>   x) is equivalent to a.append(x).

So technically when you're doing `a.insert(100, 100)` it ensures that `100` will be inserted at a index *before* 100 which happens to be, in this case, index 3.

Further, we can have a look at [the implementation](http://svn.python.org/projects/python/trunk/Objects/listobject.c):

```c
static int
ins1(PyListObject *self, Py_ssize_t where, PyObject *v)
{
    Py_ssize_t i, n = Py_SIZE(self);
    PyObject **items;
    if (v == NULL) {
        PyErr_BadInternalCall();
        return -1;
    }
    if (n == PY_SSIZE_T_MAX) {
        PyErr_SetString(PyExc_OverflowError,
            "cannot add more objects to list");
        return -1;
    }

    if (list_resize(self, n+1) == -1)
        return -1;

    if (where < 0) {
        where += n;
        if (where < 0)
            where = 0;
    }
    if (where > n)  // <-- Here the implementation handles indexes > list-len
        where = n;
    items = self->ob_item;
    for (i = n; --i >= where; )
        items[i+1] = items[i];
    Py_INCREF(v);
    items[where] = v;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Tricky wording. Before != immediately before.

Comment: @ValekHalfHeart I agree, I wish the docs would be more specific in describing the expected behavior when inserting at any possible index (even at index < 0) including the expected errors to be raised.

Comment: @ApproachingDarknessFish: That's pretty ridiculous though. Do we have to assume in some implementation `[1, 2, 3].insert(2, "foo")` might produce `["foo", 1, 2, 3]`? because `0` is before `2`... I don't like this at all. I, too, would have expected an `IndexError`, especially in such a `raise`-happy language. :/

Answer (score 9):

The documentation says:

```
L.insert(index, object) # insert object before index
```

So it seems when you try inserting at index 100 it will really get the existing index on the list before 100.

Answer (score 6):

[Perhaps the actual implementation will shed some light.](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/1cecdbbf1adef9af2ac829c7dbba91352accb1fd/Objects/listobject.c#L239)

```
static int
ins1(PyListObject *self, Py_ssize_t where, PyObject *v)
{
    ...
    if (where > n)
        where = n;
    ...
}
```

So that answers the question of how.

Philosophically, lists are not arrays, and there are many list manipulations that are tolerant of weird indexing.  For instance, l[1:1000] will return [2,3].  This is all meant as a convenience to the programmer.

Answer (score 5):

Comments by Guido van Rossum, creator of Python, on the `python-dev` mailing list (check the [September 2014 archives](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2014-September/thread.html); in my experience, the exact URLs for specific messages have a way of changing from time to time), in response to OP's crossposting of this question on that list:

> On Mon, Sep 15, 2014 at 3:46 PM, Mark Lawrence 
>   wrote:
>
> > I assume it's based on the concepts of slicing.  From the docs "s.insert(i, x) - inserts x into s at the index given by i (same as s[i:i] = [x])".
>
> Ah, right. It matches thigs like s[100:] which is the empty string if s is
>   shorter than 100.

And in another response:

> This functionality has existed since the earliest days of Python, and even if we all agreed it was wrong we couldn't change it -- it would just break too much existing code. I can't quite remember why I did it that way but it was definitely a conscious choice; probably some symmetry or edge case. (Note that it works this way at the other end too -- a.insert(-100, x) will insert x at the beginning of a, if a has fewer than 100 elements.)

Ultimately, this kind of thing is a design decision. There are almost always competing concerns, and you can never find something that will be intuitive to everyone. Just look at how many ways different languages handle a concept as fundamental as True and False (in some languages, they are identical to the numbers 1 and 0; in some languages any nonzero is True; in some languages True and False are identical to the *characters* '1' and '0' (yes, really!); in some languages they are completely incompatible with numbers or any other not-strictly-Boolean type; in some languages empty containers are False, in others they are True; the choices go on and on). Or look at nil/null/None, which also have interesting interactions with Booleans and other calculations. Some languages even have Maybe.

The way Python handles list insertion is handy in some situations, and enough people found it useful that they've written code that makes use of and depends upon insertion behaving this way. Perhaps the documentation could be a *little* clearer, but it's really not that unclear; and in any case, once you try it, you see what it does, and you write your Python code accordingly.

Comment: Ya Thanks . Was able to find at this link http://code.activestate.com/lists/python-dev/132599/

Answer (score 3):

`a.insert(len(a), x)` is [supposed](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html) to act just like `a.append(x)` for connivence. After looking at the [source code](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/d3939f602e1f/Objects/listobject.c#l262) of the method:

```
static int
ins1(PyListObject *self, Py_ssize_t where, PyObject *v)
{
    Py_ssize_t i, n = Py_SIZE(self);

    ...

    if (where > n)
        where = n;
    ...

}
```

You'll see that it handles any int above `len(a)` in the same way, by setting any int above `n` to `n`.

Therefore: any `int >= len(a)` will act just like `list.append(x)` if passed as the first argument to `list.insert(i, x)`.

The official python docs probably only recommends `len(a)` as a convenient way to make sure your always inputing a number greater than the length of the list.

Answer (score 1):

When you insert a single element into a list, the length of the list will grow by exactly one - not more, not less.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of contrasting insert to item assignment, it's more analogous to slice assignment, since both change the size of the list.

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3]
>>> a[100:100] = [100]
>>> a
[1, 2, 3, 100]
```

Slices also don't raise IndexError, and so is consistent with:

```
a.insert(100, 100)
```