# Insert an item to a Python list without using insert()

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

How do you add an item to a specific position on a list.  When you have an empty list and want to add 'z' to the 3rd position using insert() only insert it at the last position like,

```
l.insert(3,'z')
l
['z']
```

I want the output to be

```
[None, None, None, 'z']
```

or

```
['','','','z']
```

Comment: My answer on that question ^ explains why it's not possible (lists aren't sparse), and [OP's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63094414/4518341) shows something similar to what you want.

Comment: For a way to do it automatically: [Sparse assignment list in python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1857780/4518341)

Comment: How is this question the same as the flagged dup link? The answer there is "NO", whereas the question asked here has a [mre]

Comment: @wjandrea, your second link is the correct link for the answer OP is looking for

Comment: the suggested link does not answer my question.

Comment: @Akshay Djangonow edited the question right as I was voting to close as duplicate, so I got a bit confused. It's still useful for understanding, but you're right, it doesn't answer the question anymore. Voting to reopen.

Comment: Also related: [Insert object to specific list index Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62156103/4518341), [Python list set value at index if index does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22388866/4518341), [List insert at index that is well out of range - behaves like append](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25840177/4518341)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this method using a list comprehension -

```
n = 5
s = 'z'

out = [None if i!=n-1 else s for i in range(n)]
print(out)
```

```
[None, None, None, None, 'z']
```

If you want to insert the string somewhere in the middle, then a more general way is to define m and n separately where n is length of the list and m is the position -

```
n = 5
m = 3
s = 'z'

out = [None if i!=m-1 else s for i in range(n)]
print(out)
```

```
[None, None, 'z', None, None]
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to have it in the Nth index:

```
l = l[:N] + ['z'] + l[N:]
```

If you start with an empty list and want it to have Nones at the start and end of array, maybe this will help you (N is the number of None items you want):

```
l = [None] * N
l = l[:N] + ['z'] + l[N:]
```